# Best time where different values are small or high

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, analytics

I am currently analysing when the best time would be. The best time is when the `rain` is low (preferably 0), when the `temperature` is pleasant (between 10 and 30 degrees) and when the `price` is lowest and the `availabil`ity is highest.

At the moment I only carry out an analysis with the help of a plot. I can see that, for example, day 2 would be very good because the temperature is pleasant, there is no rain, the price is okay not too high and the availability is also good.

So how can I find out which days in which month are best?

If necessary, the order should be taken into account, the most important being: 1. low price, 2. little rain, 3. high availability, 4. pleasant temperature.

How could I analyse this data set so that in the end some kind of recommendation is possible?

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
d = {'year': [2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001],
     'day': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4,],
     'month': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
     'temperature': [10, 11, 12, 13, 20, 21, 22, 23],
     'rain': [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 2, 1]}
dfWeather = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(dfWeather)

import pandas as pd
d2 = {'year': [2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001],
     'day': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4,],
     'month': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
     'price': [100, 110, 120, 130, 200, 210, 220, 170],
     'available': [True, True, False, False, False, True, False, True]}
dfPrice = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
print(dfPrice)

dfAll = dfWeather.merge(dfPrice[['day', 'price', 'available', 'year', 'month']],
              on=['day', 'year', 'month'], how='outer')
print(dfAll)

plt.style.use("ggplot")
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=1,figsize=(16,10))

# Temperatur
x = dfAll.groupby('day')['temperature'].mean().index
y = dfAll.groupby('day')['temperature'].mean().values
axs[0].plot(x,y, c = '#DC727C', marker='o')


# Rain
x = dfAll.groupby('day')['rain'].mean().index
y = dfAll.groupby('day')['rain'].mean().values
axs[1].plot(x,y, c = '#FEF4A5', marker='o')

# Price
x = dfAll.groupby('day')['price'].mean().index
y = dfAll.groupby('day')['price'].mean().values
axs[2].plot(x,y, c = '#A976CD', marker='o')

# Available
x = dfAll[dfAll['available'] == True].groupby('day')['available'].count().index
y = dfAll[dfAll['available'] == True].groupby('day')['available'].count().values
axs[3].plot(x,y, c = '#378805', marker='o')


plt.show()
```

dfWeather

```py
   year  day  month  temperature  rain
0  2001    1      1           10     1
1  2001    2      1           11     2
2  2001    3      1           12     3
3  2001    4      1           13     2
4  2001    1      2           20     4
5  2001    2      2           21     1
6  2001    3      2           22     2
7  2001    4      2           23     1
```

dfPrice

```py
   year  day  month  price  available
0  2001    1      1    100       True
1  2001    2      1    110       True
2  2001    3      1    120      False
3  2001    4      1    130      False
4  2001    1      2    200      False
5  2001    2      2    210       True
6  2001    3      2    220      False
7  2001    4      2    170       True
```

dfAll

```py
   year  day  month  temperature  rain  price  available
0  2001    1      1           10     1    100       True
1  2001    2      1           11     2    110       True
2  2001    3      1           12     3    120      False
3  2001    4      1           13     2    130      False
4  2001    1      2           20     4    200      False
5  2001    2      2           21     1    210       True
6  2001    3      2           22     2    220      False
7  2001    4      2           23     1    170       True
```

You can find a dataset snippet here https://gist.github.com/Coderanker3/7b31c012bc36122d080a774c313f3a03
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new column (Let's say for example a 'score column') which will calculate the score of each row. Then you can sort by that score, giving you the best rows at the top.

Here's my example of this using the scoring system that made sense to me.

```
dfAll["score"] =  600/(dfAll["price"]+1) #price score
dfAll["score"] += 5/(dfAll["rain"]+1) #rain score
dfAll["score"] += 3.5 * dfAll["available"] #available score
dfAll["score"] += 2 / (np.log2((dfAll["temperature"] - 15).abs()+1)+1) #temprature score

print(dfAll.sort_values(by=['score'],ascending=False))
```

Note that this is probably not how you will want to calculate the score yourself. This is more so just how you would do it.

If you want to do some fancy operations on a series to calculate the score (like log2 for example) you will need to use NumPy as I have in my own example so make sure to import that at the top.

```
import numpy as np
```